# Putting precompiled azure function in a shared assembly

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Basically I'm trying to create an Azure Function as a precompiled function (as decribed on https://github.com/devkimchi/Testing-Precompiled-Azure-Functions) but with the extra Thing that I want the DLL to be in a shared Location.

My custom DLL is loaded if I put in the Directory of the function itself, but is not loaded otherwise.

So my test function Looks like this (https://github.com/devkimchi/Testing-Precompiled-Azure-Functions/blob/master/PrecompiledFunctionsApp/HttpTriggerCSharp/function.json):

```
"scriptFile": "PrecompiledLibraries.dll",
"entryPoint": "PrecompiledLibraries.MyHttpTrigger.Run"
```

But since my assembly is actually located in a shared Location, I changed it to this:

"scriptFile": "..\SharedLibraries\PrecompiledLibraries.dll",
 "entryPoint": "PrecompiledLibraries.MyHttpTrigger.Run"

But when I run the solution locally and watch the function using Sysinternals Procmon, I don't see the function app host to actually look for the file.

Specifying an absolute path doesn't work either.

What do I Need to specify here? Or is this an unsupported Scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Henning,

This is not currently supported in the released version of the Azure Functions runtime (this is actually the case for all languages, not just precompiled functions), but the good news is that this improvement has already been made and merged in (you can take a look at it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/pull/1132)) and will be in our next release.

Comment: Do you know for which date this release is scheduled?

Comment: We'll hopefully have the release out within the next couple of weeks, but I don't have a firm ETA I can provide. You can keep an eye on the releases here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/releases